# Xamarin.Forms ListView continually creates ViewCells

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I have this tiny demo that appears to show that ListView continually creates ViewCells, and binds them to the one view model, until it runs out of memory. Here's the code...

From MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LVD.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="This is a listview with one item."/>
        <Label Text="{Binding MainNum}"/>
        <ListView x:Name="DemoList" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Itms}"
                RowHeight="75"
                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    MainVM _vm = null;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _vm = new MainVM();
        BindingContext = _vm;

        DemoList.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(myCell));
    }
}
```

MainVM.cs:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace LVD
{
    class MainVM
    {
        public string MainNum { get; set; }
        private static int _mainserno = 0;
        public ObservableCollection<CellVM> Itms { get; set; }

        public MainVM()
        {
            MainNum = "Parent serial#: " + _mainserno.ToString();
            _mainserno++;
            if (Itms == null)
                Itms = new ObservableCollection<CellVM>();            
            else
                Itms.Clear();

            CellVM item = new CellVM();
            Itms.Add(item);
            //CellVM item2 = new CellVM();
            //Itms.Add(item2);
        }
    }
}
```

myCell.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace LVD
{
    class myCell : ViewCell
    {
        static int _localserialno = 0;
        Label VMnumLbl, CellNumLbl, PLbl;

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("CellItem", typeof(CellVM), typeof(myCell), null);

        public CellVM CellItem
        {
            get { return (CellVM)GetValue(ItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemProperty, value); }
        }

        public myCell()
        {
            VMnumLbl = new Label();
            VMnumLbl.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "VMSerNum", BindingMode.Default, null, "VM Serial #: {0}");

            CellNumLbl = new Label();
            CellNumLbl.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "CellSerNum", BindingMode.Default, null, "Cell Serial #: {0}");

            PLbl = new Label();
            PLbl.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "PingCount", BindingMode.Default, null, "Pings: {0}");

            var stackit = new StackLayout();
            stackit.Children.Add(VMnumLbl);
            stackit.Children.Add(CellNumLbl);
            stackit.Children.Add(PLbl);
            View = stackit;
        }

        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();

            if (BindingContext == null)
                CellItem = null;
            else if (BindingContext != CellItem)
            {
                CellItem = (CellVM)BindingContext;
                CellItem.CellSerNum = _localserialno++;
                CellItem.Ping();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CellVM.cs:

```
class CellVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private static int serialno = 0;
    private int _vmserialno;
    public int VMSerNum { get { return _vmserialno; } }
    public int CellSerNum { get; set; }
    public int PingCount { get; set; }
    public CellVM()
    {
        _vmserialno = serialno++;
        PingCount = 0;
    }

    public void Ping()
    {
        PingCount++;
        OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the display looks like this:

```
This is a listview with one item.
Parent serial #: 0
VM Serial #: 0
Cell Serial #: ++
Pings: ++
```

The bottom two numbers continually increase. That means the listview recreates the CellView, and binds them all to the same viewmodel. If I put two items in the list, both cells have running Cell Serial #'s and Pings.

Since I couldn't find anyone else complaining about this, I must be doing something wrong. Can anyone enlighten me to what that might be?

advTHANKSance  (pun intended)

Comment: Continually increase even if not touching screen? What happens if you start over, with different CachingStrategy? Why do you suspect it is running out of nemory?

Comment: Yes, without touching the screen. I've tried both Retain and Recycle element strategies. I would LOVE it if someone else would try it and see if they get the same result.  I think it's running out of memory because if I bring it up (both on device and in emulator) and don't do anything, eventually it just disappears. I don't get an out of memory error, but I don't get any other error either. After setting a ton of breakpoints, I step over the last curly-brace, then it sits, and eventually dies. The out of memory is a guess based on the increasing counters and that behavior.

Comment: I also tried removing the viewmodel (so BindingContext was set to this. And notice that there's no loop in creating the list for the listview. In my app there is, that's been removed here. It has no excuse to be looping based on my code (that I can see).

Comment: *"I would LOVE it if someone else would try it "* - Best odds of getting someone to try it, is to make a `public github repo` containing minimal code needed to build, run, see the problem. * Does it behave same if you run without debugger attached? * Maybe changing the value displayed, causes new cell to be created. I've never seen anyone make a listview with frequently changing values...

Comment: _Maybe changing the value displayed_  The initial version exhibited this behavior without changing anything. No taps or touches, no programmatic change. Nothing. I added the ping count to prove that it was happening. By the way, I did eventually find the log files that show the out of memory errors. So it does execute until there is no more memory. Maybe I should just submit this it Microsoft as a bug?